# How to skip controller in url for a default controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a following map route in ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

The `HomeController` has actions

- `Index` showing the default site page
- `Projects` showing a list of projects
- `Project` showing details about a specific project (has its id as an input)

There are other controllers in the projects.

I would like to update the routing in such a way that the urls will be the following:

- `Home` controller actions are mapped without having `Home` in the url. I do not want to list all actions in the routing definition, the rule should be generic.

  - `HomeController.Index` => `/`
  - `HomeController.Projects` => `/Projects` (or better in lower case `projects`)
  - `HomeController.Project(id: 4)` => `/Project/4` (or better in lower case `project/4`)
- Other controllers follows the standard ASP.NET routing mechanism `Controller/Action`.

What is the recommended way to achieve this? It is possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "list all actions in the routing definition"? With your current map route, you don't need to specify anything else. A controller and it's actions will automatically have the route {myurl}/ControllerName/ActionName

Comment: I mean that I do not want to have a rule for /projects, another for /project/4, another for other actions in the Home controller (I have not listed all), instead, I prefer to have a rule which will match all actions in the Home controller and produce an url which does not have the Home controller in it. The default rule would generate /Home/Products for the HomeController.Products action but /Products is expected instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "other",
    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "home",
    template: "{action=Index}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home" });
```

Answer (score 0):

To define a default controller without specifying it in the url, simply add it in the 'defaults' parameter

To combine this kind of routing in one rule, it would be cleaner to use the same base url, i.e. use `/Products` and `/Products/4`. Then you could use:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "products",
    template: "Products/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", Action = "Products" });
```

With your structure, something like this should work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "products",
    template: "{Action:regex(^(Products|Product)$)/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home" });
```

To handle urls that don't match this rule, including the base `/`, add the original default route after the products-route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "products",
    template: "{Action:regex(^(Products|Product)$)/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home" });
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```